# Projection onto kernel in an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

A quick sanity check: if a positive $x \in \mathcal{B} (\mathcal{H})$ has an isolated point $0$ in its spectrum and we define a function
$$g(t) = \begin{cases} 
1; &t = 0\\ 
0; &t \neq 0
\end{cases},$$
then $p := g(x) \in \mathcal{B} (\mathcal{H})$ is a projection. Does it project exactly onto
$\ker x$?

**Edit:** forgot that $x$ is positive.

Comment: Yes, that is true. In fact, this is true even without the assumption that $0$ is an isolated point in the spectrum, though in that case you would need to apply Borel functional calculus instead of just continuous functional calculus. This can be proved using the spectral theorem.

Comment: Since $g(x) x = x g(x) = 0$, we get $\mathrm{im}\, g(x) \subseteq \ker x$. However, I don't see how to get the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Are you aware of the general version of the spectral theorem? Something to the effect of $x$ is unitarily equivalent to a multiplication operator on a measure space?

Comment: No I'm not, but is it required to solve this?

Comment: Not really. It’s just easier and better to prove the result using the spectral theorem. I’ll just give a direct proof instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have already observed, $xg(x) = 0$ implies $\mathrm{im}(g(x)) \subseteq \ker(x)$. The definition of functional calculus also makes it clear that $g(x)$ is an orthogonal projection. So it suffices to show $\mathrm{im}(g(x)) \supseteq \ker(x)$.

Now, let $h(t) = 1 - g(t)$. Then $h(x) = 1 - g(x)$. As $g(x)$ is an orthogonal projection, we see that $\ker(h(x)) = \mathrm{im}(g(x))$. Now, $h(0) = 0$. We observe that any continuous function on $\sigma(x)$ that takes value $0$ at $t = 0$ can be uniformly approximated by a sequence of polynomials with no constant term. Indeed, if $q_i \rightarrow h$ uniformly on $\sigma(x)$, then $p_i = q_i - q_i(0) \rightarrow h$ uniformly as well. Thus, $p_i(x) \rightarrow h(x)$. We observe that, for any $\xi \in \ker(x)$, $[p_i(x)]\xi = 0$ as $x^n \xi = 0$ for all $n > 0$ and $p_i$ is a polynomial with no constant term. Hence, $[h(x)]\xi = 0$, i.e., $\ker(x) \subseteq \ker(h(x)) = \mathrm{im}(g(x))$.

Comment: This is perfectly clear. Thank you.